# Where is the issue in my nonlinear PDE solver using pseudo-spectral methods with Chebyshev collocation?

Tags: fourier-analysis, spectral-method, collocation, chebyshev, pseudospectral

This is a repost from another community, I think the question would be better here.

This bug has been haunting me for a while and would love new pair of eyes to help, not sure if this is the right place for such a question so please let me know.

I am solving a nonlinear Poisson's equation numerically using a mixed Chebyshev/Fourier spectral methods. Thus, assuming x is periodic and y is nonperiodic. I am trying to test my current numerical method/solver by using the method of manufacturing solution (MMS). Additionally, I am applying some coordinate mapping or rescaling my Chebyshev Differentiation Matrices to an arbitrary domain [a,b] by performing a change of variables as the following:

[image]

Thus, my chebyshev derivatives can be rewritten as:

[image]

The two above expressions were taken from the Weideman and Reddy paper found in this post:

[Are there any alterations for the Chebyshev Differentiation Matrices on an arbitrary domain [a,b]?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860823/are-there-any-alterations-for-the-chebyshev-differentiation-matrices-on-an-arbit)

My BCs are periodic in x and zero Dirichlet in y as $u(x,a)=0$ & $u(x,b)=0$.

Here is a simple example of my code with a simple MMS case of a non-linear Poisson's equation:

```
Nx = 4*16; 
Ny = 4*16; 
Lx =2*16;
kx  = fftshift(-Nx/2:Nx/2-1); % wave number vector
dx = Lx/Nx; 
% Use approximations for kx, and k^2. These come from Birdsall and Langdon
ksqu = (sin( kx * dx/2)/(dx/2)).^2 ;
kx = sin(kx * dx) / dx;
ksqu4inv = ksqu; 
ksqu4inv(abs(ksqu4inv)<1e-14) =1; %helps with error: matrix ill scaled because of 0s
xi_x =  2*pi/Lx;
xi  = (0:Nx-1)/Nx*2*pi;
x =  xi/xi_x;

ylow = 0;  %a
yupp =16;  %b
Ly = (yupp-ylow);
eta_ygl  = 2/Ly;
[D,etagl] = cheb(Ny);
% rescaling my Chebyshev Differentiation Matrices to an arbitrary domain [a,b] by performing a change of variables as the following:
ygl = (1/2)*((yupp-ylow)*etagl + (yupp+ylow));
D   = D*eta_ygl;
D2  = D*D;
[X,Y]   = meshgrid(x,ygl);

Igl = speye(Ny+1);
%ZNy represents the operation of setting the boundary values of y component
%to zero:
ZNy = diag([0 ones(1,Ny-1) 0]); %diag([0 ones(1,Ny-1) 0]); 
div_y_act_on_grad_y = D2* ZNy; 
%ICs
A = 2*pi / Lx;
u = (Y-ylow) .* (Y-yupp) .* sin( (A) * X);
uh = fft(u,[],2);

n = (eta_ygl)*(Y-((ylow+yupp)/2)).^2 .* sin( (3 * A) * X)+ 10;
invnek = fft(1./n,[],2);
nh = fft(n,[],2);
dnhdxk = (kx*1i*xi_x).*nh;
dnhdyk =D * nh;

%Exact source 
 ExactSource = (1/(2*(ylow - yupp)))*((-2 + ylow*A^2 *(yupp - Y) + A^2 .*Y .*(-yupp + Y)) .*sin(A*X) .*(20*(-ylow + yupp) + (ylow + yupp - 2*Y).^2 .* sin(3*A*X)) - (ylow + yupp - 2*Y).^2 .*(3*A^2 *(ylow - Y) .* (yupp - Y) .* cos(A *X).^2 .* (-1 + 2*cos(2*A*X)) + 4*sin(A*X) .*sin(3*A*X)));

oldSol = ones(size(u));
oldSolk = fft(oldSol ,[],2);
err_max =1e-4;
max_iter = 500;
Sourcek = fft(ExactSource,[],2); 
for iterations = 1:max_iter
    oldSolMax = max(max(abs(oldSolk)));
    dudxk = (kx*1i*xi_x) .*oldSolk;
    %product:
    gradNgradUx = aapx(dnhdxk,dudxk);
    dudyk = (D) *oldSolk ; 
    gradNgradUy = aapx(dnhdyk,dudyk); 
    %RHS of PDE
    RHSk = Sourcek - (gradNgradUx + gradNgradUy); 
    Stilde = aapx(invnek,RHSk);
    for m = 1:length(kx)
        L = -Igl * (ksqu4inv(m))*xi_x^2+ div_y_act_on_grad_y;
        newSolk(:,m) = L\(Stilde(:,m));

    end
        %enforce BCs    
        newSolk=[zeros(1,Nx);  newSolk(2:Ny,:); zeros(1,Nx)];
    
    newSolMax = max(max(abs(newSolk)));
    if newSolMax < err_max 
        it_error = err_max /2;
    else
        it_error = abs( newSolMax - oldSolMax ) / newSolMax ;
    end
    if it_error < err_max
        break;
    end
    oldSolk = newSolk;
 
end
%plot numerical solution vs exact
 newSol= real(ifft(newSolk,[],2)); 
 figure
 surf(X, Y, newSol);
 colorbar;
 figure
 surf(X, Y, u);
 colorbar;
```

`Cheb(N)` function is taken from Spectral Methods textbook and can be found: [HERE](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/spectral.html)

```
% CHEB compute D = differentitation matrix, x = Chebyshev grid
function [D, x] = cheb(N)
  if N == 0, D = 0; x = 1; return, end
  x = cos(pi*(0:N)/N)';
  c = [2; ones(N-1,1); 2].*(-1).^(0:N)';
  X = repmat(x,1,N+1);
  dX = X-X';
  D = (c*(1./c)')./(dX+(eye(N+1)));
  D = D - diag(sum(D'));
```

and `aapx` is a function deals with aliasing errors:

```
function ph=aapx(uh,vh) %anti-aliased product, 
% in: uh,vh from fft with n samples
%use discrete transform with m rather than n points, where m >= 3N/2
[ny nx]=size(uh);m=nx*3/2;
uhp=[uh(:,1:nx/2) zeros(ny,(m-nx)) uh(:,nx/2+1:nx)]; % pad uhat with zeros
vhp=[vh(:,1:nx/2) zeros(ny,(m-nx)) vh(:,nx/2+1:nx)]; % pad vhat with zeros
up=ifft(uhp,[],2); 
vp=ifft(vhp,[],2); 
w=up.*vp; 
wh=fft(w,[],2);
ph=1.5*[wh(:,1:nx/2) wh(:,m-nx/2+1:m)]; % extract F-coefficients
```

The issue is this code works for "certain" domain lengths and blows up for others. For example, it works fine for Lx=Ly=16 and breaks for Lx=16, and Ly=32. I have ran many debugging tests to no avail. I don't see the issue at all and the code returns no error messages to work with. Would love some feedback on how to tackle this. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As per requested here's the full description of my MMS test with results:

**I)** As an initial step I solved the **linear** Poisson's equation with the rescaled Chebyshev derivatives:
$$
\nabla^2 u = S
$$
where BCs are periodic in x and zero Dirichlet in y as $u(x,a)=0$ & $u(x,b)=0$.

For the simple above case the test I performed with the MMS is:
$$
u(x,y)=(y-a)(y-b)\sin{Ax}
$$
while $n(x,y)$ was set to 1, the above case works perfectly for me and I have no issue at all. The results of this case are the following:
[image]
As you see above the numerical matches the exact solution for different domain lengths: $L_x=32; L_y=32,64,96,..$ and the adjusted code would be:

```
Nx = 4*16; 
Ny = 4*16; 
Lx =2*16;
kx  = fftshift(-Nx/2:Nx/2-1); % wave number vector
dx = Lx/Nx; 
% Use approximations for kx, and k^2. These come from Birdsall and Langdon
ksqu = (sin( kx * dx/2)/(dx/2)).^2 ;
kx = sin(kx * dx) / dx;
ksqu4inv = ksqu; 
ksqu4inv(abs(ksqu4inv)<1e-14) =1; %helps with error: matrix ill scaled because of 0s
xi_x =  2*pi/Lx;
xi  = (0:Nx-1)/Nx*2*pi;
x =  xi/xi_x;

ylow = 0;  %a
yupp =16;  %b
Ly = (yupp-ylow);
eta_ygl  = 2/Ly;
[D,etagl] = cheb(Ny);
% rescaling my Chebyshev Differentiation Matrices to an arbitrary domain [a,b] by performing a change of variables as the following:
ygl = (1/2)*((yupp-ylow)*etagl + (yupp+ylow));
D   = D*eta_ygl;
D2  = D*D;
[X,Y]   = meshgrid(x,ygl);

Igl = speye(Ny+1);
%ZNy represents the operation of setting the boundary values of y component
%to zero:
ZNy = diag([0 ones(1,Ny-1) 0]); %diag([0 ones(1,Ny-1) 0]); 
div_y_act_on_grad_y = D2* ZNy; 
%ICs
A = 2*pi / Lx;
u = (Y-ylow) .* (Y-yupp) .* sin( (A) * X);
uh = fft(u,[],2);

n = ones(size(u)); %set to 1
invnek = fft(1./n,[],2);
nh = fft(n,[],2);
dnhdxk = (kx*1i*xi_x).*nh;
dnhdyk =D * nh;

%Linear Exact source 
 LExactSource = (4*pi^2*(ylow-Y).*(Y-yupp).*sin(A*X))/Lx^2 + 2*sin(A*X);

oldSol = ones(size(u));
oldSolk = fft(oldSol ,[],2);
err_max =1e-4;
max_iter = 500;
Sourcek = fft(LExactSource ,[],2); 
for iterations = 1:max_iter
    oldSolMax = max(max(abs(oldSolk)));
    dudxk = (kx*1i*xi_x) .*oldSolk;
    %product:
    gradNgradUx = aapx(dnhdxk,dudxk);
    dudyk = (D) *oldSolk ; 
    gradNgradUy = aapx(dnhdyk,dudyk); 
    %RHS of PDE
    RHSk = Sourcek - (gradNgradUx + gradNgradUy); 
    Stilde = aapx(invnek,RHSk);
    for m = 1:length(kx)
        L = -Igl * (ksqu4inv(m))*xi_x^2+ div_y_act_on_grad_y;
        newSolk(:,m) = L\(Stilde(:,m));

    end
        %enforce BCs    
        newSolk=[zeros(1,Nx);  newSolk(2:Ny,:); zeros(1,Nx)];

    newSolMax = max(max(abs(newSolk)));
    if newSolMax < err_max 
        it_error = err_max /2;
    else
        it_error = abs( newSolMax - oldSolMax ) / newSolMax ;
    end
    if it_error < err_max
        break;
    end
    oldSolk = newSolk;

end
%plot numerical solution vs exact
 newSol= real(ifft(newSolk,[],2)); 
 figure
 surf(X, Y, newSol);
 colorbar;
 figure
 surf(X, Y, u);
 colorbar;
```

**II)** However, when I try to do the same for the **nonlinear** Poisson's equation with following expression:
$$
\nabla \cdot (n\nabla u) = S
$$
or can be expanded as: $n \nabla^2 u + \nabla u \cdot \nabla n = S$

Then, using the MMS I chose $u(x,y)$ and $n(x,y)$ similarly as the first case:
$$
u(x,y)=(y-a)(y-b)\sin{Ax}
$$
$$
n(x,y)=\left(\frac{2}{b-a}\right)\left[y-\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \right]^2\sin{3Ax}+10
$$
For the above nonlinear case with $L_x=32, L_y=16$ I get the following results:
[image]
However, if I change my domain length along y$L_x=32L_y=32$ this results in the solution blowing up as the following:
[image]
So, basically for the nonlinear case the code works for $L_y$ from 0 to 16 then blows up! I don't seem to see a pattern to begin to understand where the issue maybe. I have done an order of accuracy test where $L_x=L_y=16$ (case where solution does NOT blow up) and it gives me expected order of accuracy so any insight here would be helpful.

Comment: I don't think anyone here can help unless you give a complete description of what the problem is you are trying to solve, and a complete description of what you observe as output. Specifically, be concise what "works fine for Lx=Ly=16 and breaks for Lx=16, and Ly=32" actually means.

Comment: Have you tested each of these components on easier problems like the linear Poisson equation? If things are blowing up with differing step sizes, that could mean that the actual differentiation matrix is off by a factor of $h$ somewhere.

Comment: @whpowell96 "Have you tested each of these components on easier problems like the linear Poisson equation?" Yes! I have and it works fine for a linear Poisson's equation for all domain lengths! I will add more details to help everyone see my issue.

Comment: @whpowell96 I have made some edits that hopefully are useful in making my problem more clear to everyone!

Comment: If what you have written is correct, it looks like your problem is actually linear in $u$, just with variable coefficient $n$. Have you tried looking at the condition number of the matrix as you change the discretization in the $y$ direction?